# Firebase: Updating - Cloud Functions for Firebase support for Node 6 runtime will shut down

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have little experience with Firebase a few days ago I was assigned a legacy project, 
which uses Firebase for push notifications, after that, I have received emails from Firebase with the following content:

> Please review your functions in your projects, listed below, and take the following actions to migrate off of the Node.js 6 runtime before August 5, 2020.
>
> To ensure that your functions are on a supported version of Node.js, please migrate to the Node.js 10 runtime as soon as possible. You may choose to upgrade to Node.js 8 however, on Dec 31, 2019, Node.js 8 was marked end-of-life by the Node.js Foundation, and will no longer be supported by Google Cloud Functions beginning February 15, 2021.
>
> - Update from Node.js 6 to Node.js 8 or Node.js 10: Specify the Node.js8 or Node.js 10 runtime explicitly by setting the `engines` field in`package.json`
>
>   - Starting June 22, 2020, to deploy Node.js 10 functions, you will need to: Make sure that your project 
>       is on the Blaze "pay-as-you-go" billing plan
>   - Enable the Cloud Build API in your project. You can do this by updating your Firebase CLI to v8.1.0 or
>       later
>
> Bear in mind that existing Node.js 10 functions will continue executing without these new requirements.
>   Starting February 15, 2021, we'll no longer support new deploys and updates of Node.js 8 functions. Then, starting March 15, 2021, we'll no longer support executions of Node.js 8 functions.

However, when I enter Cloud Function - Functions I only have a one function,
with Node.js runtime 10. 
[image: cloudfunction-function]

If I go into the source and check the package.json the engine is indicated in Node 10:
[image: package.json].

I checked the billing plan:

[image]

The CloudBuild Api : 
[image]

- Is there another place where I can see the stored functions?
- How can I identify what Node 6 refers to in the email?

Comment: Does the email not tell you which projects are affected at the bottom?

Comment: The mail indicates the project of which I show the information above, it is the only project that I have in firebase

Comment: If things don't add up, then I suggest contacting Firebase support directly.  There's probably not much Stack Overflow can do for you.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I agree with Doug, If you don't have any other function deployed with Node8 then son't worry, still in case of doub contact support

Comment: You already contacted a fire base, and they inform me that the emails are only informative, everything is fine. Thank